# BibTex: Handling manuscripts

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biblatex-dw

I have created bibliography project with books about dancing history:
https://github.com/georgthegreat/dancebooks-bibtex

It is a good practice (for manuscript entries) to add library, where this manuscript is being stored.

I failed to find field for this purpose.
So, how do I add the library to the bibliography?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). It's a much more recent system (the venerable `bibtex` is over two decades old...) If you want to stick to `bibtex`, you can either use an predefined field like `note` or you can create your own `library` field, which will be ignored, that is, it will not be listed. A relevant passage from the [`bibtex` documentation](http://ftp.roedu.net/mirrors/ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) - page 8 off CTAN:

> **ignored** - The field is ignored. BibTEX ignores any field that is not required or
>   optional, so you can include any fields you want in a bib file entry. It's a
>   good idea to put all relevant information about a reference in its bib file
>   entry - even information that may never appear in the bibliography. For
>   example, if you want to keep an abstract of a paper in a computer file, put
>   it in an `abstract` field in the paper's bib file entry. The bib file is likely
>   to be as good a place as any for the abstract, and it is possible to design a
>   bibliography style for printing selected abstracts. Note: Misspelling a field
>   name will result in its being ignored, so watch out for typos (especially
>   for optional fields, since BibTEX won't warn you when those are missing).

So, as you see, you can include it anyway. The trickier part is if you need to list it.

On the other hand, `biblatex` *does* have a `library` field defined, see the [manual](http://ftp.roedu.net/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) - page 19:

> **library** - *field (literal)*
>
> This field may be useful to record information such as a library name and a call
>   number. This may be printed by a special bibliography style if desired. Not used by
>   the standard bibliography styles.

Comment: Hmm. I'l think about biblatex. Can you give some advices about migrating from bibtex (I use bibtex8 to compile database) to biblatex?

Comment: @Georg: I think it's best if you start by reading the documentation off CTAN. It's pretty well written.

Comment: Wow! Biblatex is cool thing! No more polish notation!

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to ask a similar question and before asking it search for something similar and found yours.

Up until now I've been using biblatex's `techreport` to manage manuscripts in my bibliography-file. It looks like this:

```
@techreport{amidi:kashf:istanbul,
Author = {{Sayf al-Dīn} al-Āmidī},
Title = {Kitāb Kašf al-tamwīhāt fī Šarḥ al-Tanbīhāt},
Type = {Ms.},
Number = {Laleli 2519},     % that is the Signature
Address = {Istanbul},
Institution = {Süleymaniye Kütüphanesi}}
```

the output is:

Sayf al-Dīn al-Āmidī. *Kitāb Kašf al-tamwīhāt fī Šarḥ al-Tanbīhāt*. Ms. Laleli 2519. Istanbul: Süleymaniye Kütüphanesi.

I think the output is just like a reference to a manuscript should look like.

Still, I would like to urge the developers of biblatex to include a "manuscript" type in future versions, for - of course - a manuscript is not a tech report.

Comment: With biblatex 2.0+biber 1.0 which will be released very soon, the datamodel is dynamic so you can add any field/entrytype you like. Of course you then have to modify your style to use this field but that's easy with biblatex.